# How can i use a pdf as a image in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I want to display a picture.
The easy way i know of is to: place a image view on the interface, then choosing the attributes inspector and typing my filename (for a file that is put into my project). This works well with a png version of my picture.

But i want to use a pdf file here. Is it possible? How is the best way to show my pdf file onscreen?

Comment: You could use a web view.

Comment: how do i connect the png to the  web view?

Comment: The *PDF* would need to be set from code...

Comment: and HOW do i do that?

Comment: Use PSPDFKit,

http://pspdfkit.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option for displaying PDF is in a web view. Add a web view just like you would an image view and connect an outlet to it. Then, in code, when the view will be displayed, call:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the image scale with the web view?

Comment: Take a look at `scalesPageToFit`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to web view, if you want to present a PDF and let the user interact with it, then you can use a Document Interaction Controller. See [Document Interaction Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403).

For example:

```
- (IBAction)didTouchUpInsidePDFButton:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sample" withExtension:@"pdf"];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    controller.delegate = self;

    [controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller
{
    return self;

    // or if you want to push to the PDF preview, and the current view controller 
    // already has navigation controller, you can:
    //
    // return self.navigationController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        if (ViewModel == null)
            return;
        FirstViewModel.globalpref = "Not set yet";
        FirstViewModel.islogin = "no";
        UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Purple;
        UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(193, 168, 210);
        UITabBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(193, 168, 210);
        NewsViewModel newsViewModel = (NewsViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(NewsViewModel));
        VideoHomeViewModel videoViewModel = (VideoHomeViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(VideoHomeViewModel));
        MatchViewModel matchViewModel = (MatchViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(MatchViewModel));
        InterestsViewModel iViewModel = (InterestsViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(InterestsViewModel));
        LocationsViewModel lViewModel = (LocationsViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(LocationsViewModel));
        TicketViewModel ticketViewModel = (TicketViewModel)Mvx.IocConstruct(typeof(TicketViewModel));
        var viewControllers = new UIViewController[]
        {
            CreateTabFor("", "News",  newsViewModel),
            CreateTabFor("", "ivideo", videoViewModel),
            CreateTabFor("", "match_center", matchViewModel),
            CreateTabFor("", "ivideo", ticketViewModel),
        };
        ViewControllers = viewControllers;
        SelectedViewController = ViewControllers[0];
    }
    private int _createdSoFarCount = 0;
    private UIViewController CreateTabFor(string title, string imageName, IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var controller = new UINavigationController();
        controller.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
        controller.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        controller.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
        controller.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
        controller.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        controller.NavigationItem.Title = "test";
        var screen = this.CreateViewControllerFor(viewModel) as UIViewController;
        SetTitleAndTabBarItem(screen, title, imageName);
        controller.PushViewController(screen, true);
        return controller;
    }
    private void SetTitleAndTabBarItem(UIViewController screen, string title, string imageName)
    {
        screen.Title = title;
        screen.TabBarItem = new UITabBarItem(title, UIImage.FromBundle(imageName),
                                             _createdSoFarCount);
      //  UIImage.FromBundle("CameraIcon").Scale(new CoreGraphics.CGSize(this.TabBar.Bounds.Height - 20, this.TabBar.Bounds.Height - 20));
        _createdSoFarCount++;
    }
```

This has only been tested in Mvvmcross.iOS